# Cap maximum volume on Windows XP

Tags: windows, audio

Is there a way to cap the maximum volume on a Windows XP machine? I would like to regulate the volume so even if the user adjusts to the loudest volume, it will only be as loud as I want it to be.

Comment: There is *Sound Lock*, but unfortunately it doesn't work on XP (Vista/7 only, I think). http://www.freewaregenius.com/control-your-pcs-loudness-with-sound-lock/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way that I know of to limit the maximum volume on Windows.

I had the same issue at a library where I had to set a few systems up. In the end we put headphones on each machine.

Also, if your speakers actually have volume knobs on them, the user will simply be able to change this.

I would either use headphones or get some speakers, set them to what you want, and rip off the volume knob (but unless you put super glue on it or something, the user will be able to change it) - last being a extreme option!

Lastly, if these machines are "locked down", a option would be to set it to whatever you want, then add the volume control application to disallowed applications - but even through this method, scripts or other software that hooks directly into this function could overwrite the volume setting.

Comment: Well...thanks for concluding that there is no easy way to do this. I suppose headphones are the way to go then.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Windows XP Volume Control not enough?

Start Menu -> All Programs -> Accessories -> Entertainment -> Volume Control.

[image]

Another alternative is to make a guest account for other users. It is not 100% secure but it will keep most average users away from messing with it. Then simply remove the link to volume control from the start menu and the system tray. Make a policy to disallow the application for that user.

Comment: No. The "maximum volume" that XP will allow is too high. There are some particular users that like to turn up the volume all the way up and that is disrupting some other users. Apparently this is becoming a problem and policies haven't been working out therefore we are looking for a solution to cap the volume.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would turn the volume all the way up in XP and then adjust external speakers (with volume control) to the maximum volume you want to allow. Then tape off the physical knob. Electrical tape on black speakers doesn't look bad if you spend some time making it look pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this program fits the bill but i think it's worth mentioning:

[**VolumeLock**](http://www.actualsolution.com/volume_lock/) is an easy-to-use audio control utility that gives you the freedom in loudness control. With this program you can guarantee that the volume settings of your PC will never be changed unexpectedly. By creating your own fully customized rules for any volume control, including recording controls, you can prevent other applications from changing your volume settings. VolumeLock includes a powerful lock function, a scheduler, command line support, an ability to store and retrieve a lot of rule configurations via one mouse click or system-wide hot keys. It works with all modern sound cards and can be useful for home and power users alike.

It locks volume settings exactly where you want them, and even has a variety of 'profiles' for different times and locations. For example, quiet settings for those late night FPS bouts of carnage, or everything muted for complete audio stealth. It's up to you. Set them how you like and store your preferences in a list, for later recall.

OS: Microsoft Windows 95/98/Me/NT4/2000/XP/2003/Vista/7

*VolumeLock is shareware ($14.95), try before you buy.*

Answer (score 0):

Maximum volume on windows is important now that it is possible to listen to videos on line and advertisements added are queued up at louder than normal volumes.

This leads to hearing loss among users.