# How can I impose a software limit on volume level under Vista

Tags: windows-vista, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cap maximum volume on Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/23519/cap-maximum-volume-on-windows-xp)

I'm looking for a utility that I can install under Vista that will force the volume level not to exceed, say, 75%. My son is playing games and refuses to lower the volume. I'm looking at something that will reset the volume level to 75%, or even lower, if he raises it above 75%.

Thanks :-)

Comment: I find that yanking the power cord works.

Comment: how about a nice set of headphones for junior or earplugs for your good old self. :)

Comment: duplicate question too: http://superuser.com/questions/23519/cap-maximum-volume-on-windows-xp

Comment: @jfmessier - i posted a reference to VolumeLock in the duplicate thread, it might suit your needs.